# Restore Extended Events files from multiple directories

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

Here's a problem:

I restore extended events every day. The folders structure look like:

```
1) ServerName_20210102 -> extended files
2) ServerName_20210103 -> extended files
3) ServerName_20210104 -> extended files
```

And I want to restore Extended Events for each date. For example:
StartDate = 20210101
EndDate   = 20210105

So I wanna restore files between these two dates for each date (create table and load data into it). Looks like:

```
   1) First table - ServerName_20210101
   2) Second table - ServerName_20210102
   3) ETC.
```

I wondering how to read data from several folders?
Using this:

```
sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file ( path, mdpath, initial_file_name, initial_offset )
```

I can setup path only for one folder. Do we have any way to use several pathes in target?

Comment: `path` can contain wildcards

Comment: @Charlieface how it gonna looks like if i wanna run for ServerName_20210101 and for ServerName_20210102?

Comment: Maybe `ServerName_*\*`